# Is it possible to convert a .RPT to a .RFL?

Tags: conversion, crystal-reports

I frequently go through a multi-step process of selecting IDs from a table, which then get exported either to a DBF or copied into a cloud-based solution. Then, I run a handful of reports in Crystal Reports. My question is, is it possible to convert my existing '.rpt' files into '.rlf' files?

Comment: What is an RFL file format?

Comment: Report Layer File

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, no. RLF is not a file format Crystal Reports will export to. Below are the formats supported by Crystal Reports - Stand-Alone depending on your version. The more common formats supported are: PDF, HTML, Excel, Word, Rich Text Format (RTF), CSV, Text, XML, etc.

https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Available+Export+Formats,+Crystal+Reports+9.1+to+SAP+Crystal+Reports,+developer+version+for+Micrdsoft+Visual+Studio

[image]